# Android Webview load local content with picture resize

Tags: image, webview, resize

I have got html content from interface and show it in webview,but some pics are too large and some are very small,how should i do to make big pics fits screen and keep small pics' size?
here is my script :

```js
if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 19) {
   // 设置图片自适应（4.4以上安卓版本）
   Document doc_Dis = Jsoup.parse(content);
   Elements ele_Img = doc_Dis.getElementsByTag("img");
   if (ele_Img.size() != 0) {
    for (Element e_Img : ele_Img) {
     //if(e_Img.)
     e_Img.attr("style", "width:100%");
    }
   }
   String newHtmlContent = doc_Dis.toString();
   webView.loadDataWithBaseURL(
     com.sns.cangmin.sociax.api.Api.getHost(),
     newHtmlContent, "text/html",
     "utf-8", null);
  } else {
   // 设置图片自适应（不适合4.4以上安卓版本）
   webSetting.setLayoutAlgorithm(LayoutAlgorithm.SINGLE_COLUMN);
   webSetting.setBuiltInZoomControls(true); // 设置显示缩放按钮
   webSetting.setSupportZoom(true); // 支持缩放
   webView.loadDataWithBaseURL(
     com.sns.cangmin.sociax.api.Api.getHost(),
     content, "text/html", "utf-8",
     null);
  }
```

but small pics are resize to screen width in 4.4.4  ,  how should i do it??

Comment: here  i solved it by :
e_Img.attr("style", "max-width:100%");   

haha,happy

Comment: Thanks you are awesome ! +1 point